# Não consigo colocar resultado na tabela SQL

Tags: oracle

Quero colocar o resultado dessa equação ali aonde está 'RESULT1' já tentei fazer

result1 = x

Más não funcionou, tenho pouca experiência com SQL ainda;

```
SELECT (VA * VB) / VC    
   FROM (SELECT 5 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 5 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 1 AS VA, 1  AS VB, 1 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 3 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 2 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL);
```

Tentei fazer assim,

```
   SELECT RESULT1 = (VA * VB) / VC    
   FROM (SELECT 5 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 5 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 1 AS VA, 1  AS VB, 1 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 3 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 2 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: Obrigado mais já resolvi

Answer (score 2):

Tens de usar a clausula **into**:

```
 SELECT (VA * VB) / VC   into RESULT1 
   FROM (SELECT 5 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 5 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 1 AS VA, 1  AS VB, 1 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL UNION
         SELECT 3 AS VA, 10 AS VB, 2 AS VC, X AS RESULT1 FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo mais já resolvi de outra forma.